# Adding Minipage

Tags: minipage, cv

I want to write CV for that I want to divide the page into 2 mini page of different size. Also, in the title I want to add the image to the right and add the details to the left. I'm attaching an image for more insight to my problem.

Thanks for helping in advance.[image]

Comment: Why don´t you just use the moderncv-documentclass?

Comment: You are not sharing which template you are using. Without that information, every solution will be based on guesses.

Answer (score 1):

TeX typesetting is all about boxes. If you are ready to manually adjust dimensions, all you need is to enclose your suitably sized minipages in boxes:

```
\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\mbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
text [...]
\end{minipage}}\hspace{1cm}\vrule
\mbox{
\begin{minipage}[t]{4cm}
text [...]
\end{minipage}}
```

Furthermore, I've added some space and a rule `vrule`to illustrate how easily it can be done. Be aware that no pagebreak can happen in a minipage, hence all content has to be tuned manually.

[image]

For your image, just precede it with `\hfill` (extensible space) that will fill all available space between your text to the left and your picture to the right.